# dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier change multiple UIPickerviews Value

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uipickerview

I am creating a custom cell which have pickerView, when I run the app it loads all cells with picker view. At a time 4 cells are visible, When i change the value of first picker view and scroll down. Value of every 4th picker has been changed. I get the values of all picker views, it returns correct value, means it only changes the value of first picker view.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

     AddTaskTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"addTaskCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    AddTaskDetails *task =[self.tasksArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSAttributedString *attributedString = [self attributedTextForTask:task.taskDetail];
    cell.taskDetails.attributedText = attributedString;
    cell.hourePicker.tag = indexPath.row;
    [cell.hourePicker selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:YES];
    cell.addDescriptionBtn.tag = indexPath.row;

    [cell.addDescriptionBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(didTapAddDescButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return  cell; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After wasting 6 hours, I have solved the problem and here is the updated code:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

     AddTaskTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"addTaskCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    AddTaskDetails *task =[self.tasksArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSAttributedString *attributedString = [self attributedTextForTask:task.taskDetail];
    cell.taskDetails.attributedText = attributedString;
    cell.hourePicker.tag = indexPath.row;

    cell.addDescriptionBtn.tag = indexPath.row;

    [cell.addDescriptionBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(didTapAddDescButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    AddTaskDetails *task_1 =[self.tasksArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if(task_1.hours>0)
    {
       [cell.hourePicker selectRow:task_1.hours inComponent:0 animated:NO];
    }
    else
    {
         [cell.hourePicker selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:NO];
    }

    return  cell;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because the cell is being re-used but never having the picker reset.

When configuring your cell for display, you need to set the picker to a default value before setting it to the correct value for that cell (if applicable).

You'll need to store the value selected in the picker somewhere other than the table cell. The table cell will be re-used so you need a data structure (presumably your data source).

Comment: I have done that. But now if i scroll my tableview it reset all the picker views to default value.

Comment: Can you provide your method for dequeueing cells?

Where are you storing the value that is selected in the picker?

Comment: Thanks, Please vote up my question, if you thinks it will be helpful for others.

Answer (score 0):

Set picker view value for each cell in

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

if you don't set it here for each cell, picker view values will be strange. The reason its showing same values after scrolling is because iOS is just picking up the visible cells and displaying them again on scrolling. So unless you set the values in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` , they will have previous values.